# Min Height for GridLayout Row set to Auto

Tags: layout, nativescript

In a GridLayout, I have set a row to 'auto' because the content size is dynamic.  In particular, I have a pulldown menu in the row.  When it opens, the row correctly grows to the height of the pulldown list that appears.  BUT, when the pulldown is closed, it is merely a button that should have the same height as the other rows.  Unfortunately, the row height is a bit too small and causes the overall layout to look bad.

To fix this, I need to set the minimum height of the 'auto' row.  Is this possible?  Can I set a minimum height for a GridLayout row that is set to 'auto' ???

Answer (score 1):

You can not set minimum height for a particular grid row, instead you can set `minHeight` (`min-height` with CSS) on the Button you are talking about / simply wrap the Button with a ContentView / StackLayout if you like to keep the Button smaller while giving it more space.